# Sorting, grouping & counting a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am a designer working on a code igniter project and I am stuck on this problem!

I have this array

```
Array
(
     [Science] => 7
[War] => 5
[Mystery] => 2
[Preview Only] => 2
[Conspiracy,News ] => 2
[Drugs,Educational,Lifestyle,Society] => 1
[Educational,Nature,Science,Space] => 1
[Religion,Society] => 1
[Music] => 1
[Movies,Music] => 1
[Lifestyle] => 1
[Countries,Educational,History,War] => 1
[Educational,Society] => 1
[Science,Space,Technology] => 1
[Economics,Educational,Lifestyle,Society] => 1
[Society] => 1
[Biology,Conference,Educational] => 1
[Human Rights,Society] => 1
[Art and Artists,Biographies,Music] => 1
[Biology,Educational,Science] => 1
[Activist,Biology,Science,Society] => 1
[Countries,Drugs,War] => 1
[Drugs,War] => 1
[Technology,War] => 1
[History,War] => 1
[Biology,Educational,Environment,Nature,Science] => 1
[Science,Technology] => 1
[Educational,Science,Space] => 1
[Educational,History,Human Rights,War] => 1
[Environment] => 1
[Biographies] => 1
[Evolution,Science] => 1
[Art and Artists] => 1
)
```

As you can see there it is already ordered by a number. What I would like to achieve is removing any duplicate categories from the array and adding a +1 to each category, leaving me with this result:

```
Array
(
[Science] => 14
[War] => 11
[Mystery] => 2
[Preview Only] => 2
[Conspiracy] => 2
[Society] => 4
[Nature] => 1
[space] => 1
[Religion] => 1
[Music] => 2
[Movies] => 1
[Lifestyle] => 1
[Countries] => 1
[Educational] => 12
[Space] => 1
[Lifestyle] => 1
[Society] => 3
[Biology] => 3
[Economics] => 1
[Science] => 1
[Activist] => 1
[Countries] => 1
[Drugs] => 3
[Technology] => 2
[History] => 1
[Biology] => 1
[Technology] => 1
[Space] => 1
[History] => 1
[Human Rights] => 
[Environment] => 1
[Biographies] => 2
    [Evolution] => 1
    [Art and Artists] => 1
)
```

The examples don't perfectly match but you can see what I am trying to achieve. THANKS EVERYONE!!!

Comment: If importance is whether a combination (`[Activist,Biology,Science,Society]` for instance) can have have a value of more then 1?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_keys()` to get the key of the first array, `explode()` to cut the commas, and then, if explode gave more than one element, check if that element exists or not, and increment by one, or create a new.

This a first version, not even tested:

```
   $array1 = array(); // The array you show
   $array2 = array(); // The resulting array

   $keys = array_keys($array1);
   foreach($keys as $key)
   {
        $chunks = explode(',', $key);
        foreach($chunks as $chunk)
        {
             if(isset($array2[$chunk]))
                 $array[$chunk] += $array1[$key];
             else
                 $array[$chunk] = $array1[$key];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, your first answer was sort of correct, however, the code example you've edited in is _not_ (hardcoded `1`'s is not the way to go).

Comment: I did it in the moment, and, as you point, there are previous values, I'll change it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
function do_the_magic( $array ){
 $result = array();
 foreach ($array as $k=>$value){
  foreach (explode(',',$k) as $category){
   $result[$category] += $value;
  }
 }
 return $result;
}
```

example:

```
$a['ala,ma']=1;
$a['ala']=2;
print_r(do_the_magic($a));
```

results in

```
Array ( 
 [ala] => 3 
 [ma] => 1 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$result = array();
foreach($data as $str_keys => $value) {
    $keys = explode(',', $str_keys);
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        if(isset($result[$key])) {
            $result[$key] += $value;
        } else {
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}

print_r($result);
```